# CSS "width: auto" is not working on <div>

Tags: html, css

I want `.test_info` be width auto, not the same as the width of `#test`.

https://jsfiddle.net/ef6ukobf/

```css
#test {
  background: #26A65B;
  height: 30px;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -8px;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-right: -8px;
}
.test_info {
  background: #00ff00;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div class="test_info">50</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `<div>` element is block level, by default it takes the entire available width of the container.

If you want it to be ***auto*** width (depends on the content inside), you can do:

```
.test_info {
  display: inline-block; /*or table*/
}
```

```css
#test {
  background: #26A65B;
}
.test_info {
  background: #00ff00;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div class="test_info">50</div>
</div>
```